# What is the value of $2^{3000}$

Tags: exponentiation, computational-mathematics

What is the value of $2^{3000}$?

How to calculate it using a programming language like C#?

Comment: The value is best put as $2^{3000}$. In binary, it's a 1 followed by 3000 zeros. The number is roughly 900 decimal digits long, so unless you have good reason to express it in decimal, you're probably better off with binary.

Comment: This number is way too big to be represented in a computer, the only way is to create a custom object and handle the computation yourself using strings (store the numbers in strings).

You can also try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/3d4d2eb0-2f49-485d-ba99-1e5fa77d7599/

Comment: In most programming languages, you need some sort of big number package.  Then there will be an operation for it, which will result in a proper representation of the number.  In some, like Python, Mathematica, PARI/GP it is built in

Comment: So, I guess the question is not: "what is the value" but "what is the decimal representation"??  Another question I can answer: "What is its prime factorization?"

Comment: @Hermann It is certainly not too big to be represented in a computer (e.g. I can compute it on my phone using the Android version of Maxima). Probably what you meant to write is that the integer  is too big to be represented in a *single machine word* of existing computers.

Comment: Why does this question keep getting down votes?  The FAQ makes it clear that questions concerning mathematical software *is* on topic.  While fairly elementary, this question is not just about mathematical software, but about the *mathematics* of mathematical software.

Comment: I honestly think this question is off topic here and it belongs to comuputer stuff.

Comment: Its very commom to see "computer stuff" working together with "mathematical stuff". Depends a lot of the context of the problem, you can't just put a wall between this two stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C# (.Net 4.0 or higher) you can obtain the desired value like this:

String result = BigInteger.Pow(2, 3000).ToString();

Answer (score 24):

1230231922161117176931558813276752514640713895736833715766118029160058800614672948775360067838593459582429649254051804908512884180898236823585082482065348331234959350355845017413023320111360666922624728239756880416434478315693675013413090757208690376793296658810662941824493488451726505303712916005346747908623702673480919353936813105736620402352744776903840477883651100322409301983488363802930540482487909763484098253940728685132044408863734754271212592471778643949486688511721051561970432780747454823776808464180697103083861812184348565522740195796682622205511845512080552010310050255801589349645928001133745474220715013683413907542779063759833876101354235184245096670042160720629411581502371248008430447184842098610320580417992206662247328722122088513643683907670360209162653670641130936997002170500675501374723998766005827579300723253474890612250135171889174899079911291512399773872178519018229989376

Found using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E3000)

Comment: (-!) What do u want to show by copy pasting from wolfram?

Comment: I believe this answers one of the two questions that were asked; not everyone is aware of this tool.

Comment: Interesting, actually. I would not have even tried...

Comment: Ok then but still I don't consider it an answer.It should have been a comment either as use wolfram.

Comment: @exploringnet I think this is a pretty adequate answer to such question. He asked for value and he got it. If it seems useless to you - blame the question not the answer.

Comment: + 1 for answering first part of the question.

Comment: It is somewhat depressing that this is my #2 answer of all time.

Comment: Update: it is particularly depressing that this is now my #1 answer of all time. I can only assume that this is why all the upvotes.

Comment: @vadim123 : depressing? my #1 answer in SO (out of 764) is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10193931/277304)

Answer (score 13):

In order to avoid numerical overflow problems, some kind of [arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) is required to store numbers this large.  Many computer algebra systems include arbitrary precision arithmetic.

One may also use a bignum library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).  Here's a C implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main() {
  mpz_t two,two_to_the_three_thousand;

  mpz_init_set_ui(two,2);
  mpz_init(two_to_the_three_thousand);

  mpz_pow_ui(two_to_the_three_thousand,two,3000);

  gmp_printf("%Zd\n",two_to_the_three_thousand);

  mpz_clear(two);
  mpz_clear(two_to_the_three_thousand);

  return 0;
}
```

which we compile with [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) by:

```
gcc temp.c -lgmp
```

which outputs

```
1230231922161117176931558813276752514640713895736833715766118029160058800614672948775360067838593459582429649254051804908512884180898236823585082482065348331234959350355845017413023320111360666922624728239756880416434478315693675013413090757208690376793296658810662941824493488451726505303712916005346747908623702673480919353936813105736620402352744776903840477883651100322409301983488363802930540482487909763484098253940728685132044408863734754271212592471778643949486688511721051561970432780747454823776808464180697103083861812184348565522740195796682622205511845512080552010310050255801589349645928001133745474220715013683413907542779063759833876101354235184245096670042160720629411581502371248008430447184842098610320580417992206662247328722122088513643683907670360209162653670641130936997002170500675501374723998766005827579300723253474890612250135171889174899079911291512399773872178519018229989376
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is what I got using [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)  by typing `2^3000`

[image]

- **PARI is a C library**, allowing fast computations.
- gp is an easy-to-use interactive shell giving access to the PARI functions. GP is the name of gp's scripting language.

Answer (score 5):

A MATLAB solution seems fit for I believe there are lots of MATLAB/Octave users here.

There is a [Variable Precision Integer Arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725) package in MATLAB file exchange that creates a class named `vpi`, and all relevant methods like `power`, `log`, etc. The usage is like MATLAB built-in `uint32` or `unit64`. Add path to whichever folder that has this package. Type

`>> A = vpi(2)^3000`

`>> A =
   123023192216111717693155881327675251464071389573683371576611802916005
880061467294877536006783859345958242964925405180490851288418089823682358
508248206534833123495935035584501741302332011136066692262472823975688041
643447831569367501341309075720869037679329665881066294182449348845172650
530371291600534674790862370267348091935393681310573662040235274477690384
047788365110032240930198348836380293054048248790976348409825394072868513
204440886373475427121259247177864394948668851172105156197043278074745482
377680846418069710308386181218434856552274019579668262220551184551208055
201031005025580158934964592800113374547422071501368341390754277906375983
387610135423518424509667004216072062941158150237124800843044718484209861
032058041799220666224732872212208851364368390767036020916265367064113093
699700217050067550137472399876600582757930072325347489061225013517188917
4899079911291512399773872178519018229989376`

And the data type of `A` can be retrieved by

`>> class(A)`

`ans =vpi`

Pretty useful for people working on encryption.

Answer (score 3):

On a pocket calculator (using natural logs to restrict to the functions available in most computer languages), I computed
$$
3000\times\frac{\log(2)}{\log(10)}=903.089986991943
$$
I then computed
$$
\exp(0.089986991943\times\log(10))=1.23023192215946
$$
Thus, getting
$$
2^{3000}=1.23023192216\times10^{903}
$$
I trimmed off three digits from the mantissa since I lost three digits of significance in the log to $903$.

Not exact, but it might do in a pinch.

---

For a more exact answer, the following Java expression should do the trick

`BigInteger("2").pow(3000).toString()`