# Prove that $5^n - 2^n$ is divisible by $3$ for all nonnegative integers $n$ using mathematical induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Using mathematical induction, prove for all integers n  1 that $5^n - 2^n$ is divisible by 3.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The answer here on [Why is every answer of $5^k - 2^k$ divisible by 3?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372976/why-is-every-answer-of-5k-2k-divisible-by-3) has an induction approach.

Comment: @1ftw1 [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283056/induction-proof-help-number-theory-george-e-andrews-1-1-3).

Comment: I guess you mean **nonnegative** integers $n$. I've edited the title.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that $5^{n+1}-2^{n+1} = 5\cdot 5^n - 2\cdot 2^n = 5(5^n-2^n) + 3\cdot2^n$.

Answer (score 3):

This one could be solved by induction but is it much neater if you use that 
\[ a^n-b^n = (a-b) \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i\cdot  b^{n-1-i} \]
If you use this one in your problem you see that 
\[ 5^n- 2^n = (5-2) \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 5^i \cdot 2^{n-1-i}=3 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 5^i \cdot 2^{n-1-i}\]
Which can be dived by $3$.

If you really want to use Induction use that 
\[ 5=3+2\]
(ok this hint seems ridicolous it shall be used like this)
\[ 5^{n+1} - 2^{n+1} = (3+2) \cdot 5^n - 2 \cdot 2^n= 3 \cdot 5^n+ 2(5^n-2^n)\]